# Vue Prop Undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm passing a prop to a component and the prop is coming up undefined.

I have set the prop name a few times in different ways and also tested it but nothing seems to pass it

I set the data here

```
showUserModal(id) {
      this.showUser = true;
      $("#singleAllUser").modal("show");
      this.passUserId = id;
      this.showUserRecord = true;
    },
```

the data is as follows:

```
passUserId: "",
```

Then bind it to the modal here

```
    <singleUser v-show="showUser" :modal.sync="showUserRecord" v-bind:userid="passUserId"></singleUser>
```

then inside the modal I pick it up as

```
props: {
    userid: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
```

The result im getting is Undefined and I cant see why

Comment: Because `userid` does not equal `betid`?...

Comment: sorry I gave you the wrong code snippet, it is userid

Comment: What's the value of `id` if you console.log it inside `showUserModal`? It might be `undefined` there as well. It would be better if you create a minimal and working example, it would be easier and faster to resolve.

Comment: It is undefined yes, It's strange as the same code works perfectly on another component

Comment: Can you show the code where you are accessing the `userid` prop in your child component? That prop doesn't have a default value, so if you are trying to access it before the `showUserModal` method has run, it'll be `undefined`.